# symbol not found error in Trace32 cmm script

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

```
LOCAL &aVariable
&aVariable = Var.Val('\someheader.h\SOMEMACRO')
```

where SOMEMACRO was defined in the header as a static const and in a diffErent sub-directory as the cmm script

Answer (score 0):

Check the windows `sYmbol.Browse` and `sYmbol.List.MACRO` if you can find SOMEMACRO in there.

If you can't find your macro, check if you have loaded your ELF with option **/MARCO** at command `Data.LOAD.Elf`

If you still can't find your macro, your ELF file does most likely not have the macro names inside the debug information included in your ELF. In this case, check the build options of your compiler, if it allows to add names of your macros to the ELF's debug information (e.g. GCC does this with `-g3`)